# Terminate socket receive in .NET core

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm in the progress of writing a client/server socket library in .NET core, just a basic model for use inside another project.

In the client, I've got three threads, one listening, one sending, and one which passes the received messages back to the consumer.

I'm trying to implement a Shutdown function to close the client. Sending and receiving functions are both consumers, so they're easy to just tell to check for a ManualResetEvent.

However, the only way I can find to close the receiving thread is to run socket.Shutdown() since the tread is stuck in socket.Recieve(). This causes a SocketException to be thrown in the listening thread, which can be caught, handled and cleanly closed. However, my issue occurs when I can't determine the NativeErrorCode of the SocketException to know why it's closing.

I don't want to hide errors by catching all SocketExceptions, just the NativeErrorCode 10004 error. NativeErrorCode is not accessiable in the SocketException class, however I can see it in IntelliSense, any ideas?

```
 private void ListenThread()
    {
        //Listens for a recieved packet, first thing reads the 'int' 4 bytes at the start describing length
        //Then reads in that length and deserialises a message out of it
        try
        {
            byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[4];
            while (socket.Receive(lengthBuffer, 4, SocketFlags.None) == 4)
            {
                int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);
                if (msgLength > 0)
                {
                    byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[msgLength];
                    socket.Receive(messageBuffer);
                    messageBuffer = Prereturn(messageBuffer);
                    Message msg = DeserialiseMessage(messageBuffer);
                    receivedQueue.Enqueue(msg);
                    receivedEvent.Set();
                    MessagesRecievedCount += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            //Need to detect when it's a good reason, and bad, NativeErrorCode does not exist in se
            //if(se.NativeErrorCode == 10004)
            //{

           // }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of se.NativeErrorCode you may use se.SocketErrorCode(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError), it is more clear.

Also, i usually use async sockets. They are built on the event model, so if something arrives to а socket buffer, a callback func will be called

```
    public void ReceiveAsync()
    {
       socket.BeginReceive(tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length, 0, ReadCallback, this);//immediately returns 
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)//is called if something is received in the buffer as well as if other side closed connection - in this case countBytesRead will be 0
    {
       int countBytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
       if (countBytesRead > 0)
       {
           //read tempBytes buffer
       }
    }
```